# Is it safe to use the command apt-get autoremove in this particular scenario?

Tags: apt, package-management

The last time I used `sudo apt-get autoremove`, nearly every important display driver or parts got deleted. This made me very squeamish about using the command again. However, each time I install something or use `apt-get update` the terminal reads:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  devilspie libturbojpeg:i386 libxrandr-ltsr2 language-pack-kde-en
  kde-l10n-engb language-pack-kde-en-base libxv1:i386 libllvm3.2
  libllvm3.2:i386 linux-generic-lts-raring
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
```

I tried the command `clean` and the messages stops displaying for a while. My question is whether it's safe running the `autoremove` command, or will I lose everything once again? Is there a way of checking how safe it is to use `autoremove` in this particular (or any) case?

Comment: `autoremove` itself will only remove left over dependencies of packages you no longer have. If you uninstalled a main package (like Ubuntu desktop) `autoremove` might have gotten confused and removed other things it didn't think you needed anymore. I've used `autoremove` a lot and never had any problems.

Comment: Is there a way of checking if it's safe? Because I **did** have problems using it.

Comment: It will verify with you before it removes any packages.

Comment: No need to add a extra line between them ;).

Comment: Lol @Braiam , I figured if you make it more readable, you were probably right to do so. Tried to make it even better :)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

To focus on your past experience, if `autoremove` is going to remove "more than you intended", it's only doing that because those packages are no longer depended upon. That happens when you accidentally remove something :)

A common example from the good old days would be removing something Compiz-related. `apt-get` would show you a list of Compiz packages it was going to remove and you'd miss that `ubuntu-desktop` was also in there. `ubuntu-desktop` is just a meta-package that depends on all the packages that make up the desktop so removing it doesn't directly remove anything...

... But when you do an subsequent `autoremove`, all those things that `ubuntu-desktop` was the sole dependency... They're going bye-bye.

A few lessons:

- `sudo apt-get remove <package>` will warn you what it's going to remove directly. It won't notify you about knock-on effects.
- `sudo apt-get autoremove` should also warn you what it's going to do.
- Use `apt-get -s autoremove` to do a simulated dry run if you're unsure. You can use that  on all `apt-get` commands.
- If you reboot and you're staring at TTY1 wondering what the monkeys you've nuked this time, `/var/log/apt/history.log` should have you most recent activity.
- If in doubt, check `ubuntu-desktop` is installed.

Is `autoremove` *safe*? It's heavy machinery so it's only as safe as the driver... But that said, it's hard to do permanent damage.

Comment: Thank you, this was actually the answer I needed. Thanks for at least reading through the entire post before making assumptions due to the title and thinking tl;dr. The -s flag was the information I was looking for.

Comment: It's not safe! I just killed my `ros` installation because `apt` thought it would be a nice idea to autoremove it. No I cannot reinstall it because of `unmet Dependencies` and  ` held broken packages` :(. What a mess!!!!

Comment: @mcExchange It will have **warned and prompted** you before it did any of that. Per the last line, it's only as safe as the person using it.

Comment: Yes I was warned / prompted then I read your answer and felt that it was safe doing it. However it's a semi catastrophe! I thought it's at least worth mentioning it. Ubuntu is extremely sensible when it comes to dependencies. Maybe it was the fault of the `ros`  developpers but who cares. It's just miserable how easily one can fall into the dependency hell on a Ubuntu system

Comment: I will never run `autoremove` to save few megabytes (or, few hundred megabytes) disk space and to improve few milliseconds startup time.

Answer (score 5):

> The following packages were automatically installed and **are no longer required**

If they are no longer required apt will know when it builds the dependencies. apt-get just inform you "Hey, you removed something that installed these packages. I prefer that you decide what to do with them since **you are the boss**".

Now, it is safe? Yes. What happen if you need em again? apt will download them. Should I check the list? Yes. A light check might be needed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the confusing part for me is that one time where I used apt-get autoremove and it left me with only the CLI and no x-server. The pain this cost me to reinstall (read: time and effort) was just not funny anymore.

Comment: @Nkciy84 that was because you probably removed a meta-package. And didn't read the packages that you will uninstall. IMO, apt ask you if you remove a package that will leave the system crippled/unbootable so, only if you read that will remove some 100 packages you do not need to worry.

Comment: it handily autoremoved ALL my network drivers. I'm pretty sure they were required! :(

Comment: @JamesRyan you had the list of packages asking you for confirmation. Also, I'm pretty sure you didn't installed those package, since they were marked as automatically installed.

Comment: @Braiam it didn't ask me for confirmation, and whether they were installed automatically is irrelevant when the PC has now been cut off and I have to faff around trying to fix it with usb sticks.  My underlying problem was that ubuntu filled up the /boot partition.  None of this is stuff a user should need to touch, it is plain bad user experience created by ubuntu.

Comment: @JamesRyan https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/7f18715769a93da7a99438f6de4e2533ac8c7ed8/doc/apt.8.xml#L97

Comment: @Braiam you are totally missing the point. Users should not need to fix dependencies of bog standard hardware and routine upgrade processes. They should not need to care how autoremove works. This attitude is why Ubuntu will never replace Windows.

Comment: @JamesRyan you are *missing the point*. apt ask *you* for confirmation, so the onus of the verification *is yours*. apt shouldn't know, and effectively can't know, which packages you don't wish to remove. That's on you.

Answer (score 2):

Unsafe example:

```
apt-get remove --purge icedove*
```

***Never, almost never use an asterisk except for libreoffice***

With great power comes great responsibility.
Generally you should use the synaptic package manager which offers much better presentation (warnings**) then the terminal.

For example on debian Jessie (8.2) I noticed imagemagick was not functioning and that there were 2 shortcuts to it in the menu of a default install.  I started with:

```
apt-get remove --purge imagemagick
```

That got rid of one shortcut, then I launched synaptic and two packages were left one of those being imagemagick-common.  Upon selecting that package for complete removal it showed inkscape as the 1st thing that had to be removed as a consequence among many others.

Now do the same thing in the terminal, and it won't jump at you nearly as much.  It might not phase you at all  unless you're a linux veteran.