# Is apt autoremove safe?

Tags: apt

Regarding the command `apt autoremove`, is it safe to use? Will it remove
only unneeded files? Are there any reasons to use caution when running it?

Comment: See this https://askubuntu.com/a/393307/

Comment: @pomsky I just had to react to your comment with :D

Comment: Read `man apt` or see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt.8.html . Also "Safe" is too broad a concept.