# Meaning of the following messages on terminal

Tags: 16.04, command-line, apt, java

I had tried to install java in my system by following the instructions in the page: [Java Installation Instr Oracle](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml)

Now, when I typed java -version, it gave me the following messages:

```
 The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

Realizing that I may not have configured the path var correctly, I added the following lines to /etc/environment:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/Java/jre1.8.0_161"
export JAVA_HOME
```

Now, the content of the /etc/environment file has become:

PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
    JAVA_HOME="/usr/Java/jre1.8.0_161"
    export JAVA_HOME

Despite changing the above file, it still showed me `The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:` error.

Hence, I decided to use

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*
```

And I got the following messages:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-jre-headless' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jdk' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jre' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-6-jdk' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-6-jre' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-demo' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-6-jre-headless' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-demo' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jre-dcevm' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jdk-headless' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-dbg' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-7-jre-headless' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-doc' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jre-zero' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-source' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-jre' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-jdk' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-jre' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-7-jdk' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-7-jre' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-jdk-headless' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jre-headless' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-source' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jre-jamvm' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-dbg' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-doc' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Package 'openjdk-6-jdk' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-7-jre-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-6-jre-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-7-jre' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-6-jre' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-7-jdk' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-jre' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jre-dcevm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-9-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-9-demo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-9-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-9-jdk' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-9-jdk-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-9-jre' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-9-jre-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-9-source' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-demo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jdk' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jdk-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jre' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jre-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jre-jamvm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-source' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jre-zero' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.10.0-28 linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-31 linux-headers-4.13.0-31-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-32 linux-headers-4.13.0-32-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-36 linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic
  linux-image-4.10.0-28-generic linux-image-4.13.0-31-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-31-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.10.0-28-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-31-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.13.0-32-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-36-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 144 not upgraded.
```

Now I decided to go ahead and use:

```
sudo apt autoremove  openjdk-\*
```

For which I got the following result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-jre-headless' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jdk' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jre' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-6-jdk' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-6-jre' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-demo' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-6-jre-headless' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-demo' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jre-dcevm' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jdk-headless' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-dbg' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-7-jre-headless' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-doc' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jre-zero' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-source' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-jre' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-jdk' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-jre' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-7-jdk' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-7-jre' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-jdk-headless' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jre-headless' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-9-source' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-jre-jamvm' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-dbg' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Note, selecting 'openjdk-8-doc' for glob 'openjdk-*'
Package 'openjdk-6-jdk' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-7-jre-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-6-jre-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-7-jre' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-6-jre' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-7-jdk' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-jre' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jre-dcevm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-9-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-9-demo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-9-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-9-jdk' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-9-jdk-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-9-jre' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-9-jre-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-9-source' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-demo' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jdk' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jdk-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jre' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jre-headless' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jre-jamvm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-source' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'openjdk-8-jre-zero' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-4.10.0-28 linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-31 linux-headers-4.13.0-31-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-32 linux-headers-4.13.0-32-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-36 linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic
  linux-image-4.10.0-28-generic linux-image-4.13.0-31-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-31-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.10.0-28-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-31-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.13.0-32-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-36-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 20 to remove and 144 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1,269 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 364130 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic (4.10.0-28.32~16.04.2) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.10.0-28 (4.10.0-28.32~16.04.2) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.13.0-31-generic (4.13.0-31.34~16.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.13.0-31 (4.13.0-31.34~16.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.13.0-32-generic (4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.13.0-32 (4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic (4.13.0-36.40~16.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.13.0-36 (4.13.0-36.40~16.04.1) ...
Removing linux-signed-image-4.10.0-28-generic (4.10.0-28.32~16.04.2) ...
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-31-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Removing linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic (4.10.0-28.32~16.04.2) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.10.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.10.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic
Adding /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.10.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.10.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.10.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.10.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-31-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Removing linux-image-4.10.0-28-generic (4.10.0-28.32~16.04.2) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.10.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.10.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-31-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Removing linux-signed-image-4.13.0-31-generic (4.13.0-31.34~16.04.1) ...
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-31-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Removing linux-image-extra-4.13.0-31-generic (4.13.0-31.34~16.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.13.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.13.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-31-generic
Adding /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.13.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.13.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.13.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.13.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-31-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Removing linux-image-4.13.0-31-generic (4.13.0-31.34~16.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.13.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-31-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.13.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-32-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Removing linux-signed-image-4.13.0-32-generic (4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1) ...
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-32-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Removing linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic (4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-32-generic
Adding /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-32-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Removing linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic (4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-32-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.13.0-32-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Removing linux-signed-image-4.13.0-36-generic (4.13.0-36.40~16.04.1) ...
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Removing linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic (4.13.0-36.40~16.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.13.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.13.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Adding /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.13.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.13.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.13.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.13.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
Removing linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic (4.13.0-36.40~16.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.13.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.13.0-36-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

Could you please tell me what exactly has happened after sudo apt-autoremove. Has it messed up with any of the boot partitions or reconfigured something differently that might cause trouble? I have a dual booted system (Windows and Ubuntu). I am a complete noob in linux and had blindly followed some links online to freshly install java.

Simple, Clear answers will be much apprecitated.

Comment: Do **not** use `export` in the `/etc/environment` file. It is not a shell script. The syntax is `key=value`, nothing else, except for comments.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Should I type the export command in the terminal? Or should i add it somewhere else?

Comment: you can use export if you are setting it in `.bash_profile` or `.profile` etc.. something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/18972665/4826457

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Despite changing the above file, it still showed me The program 'java' can be found in the following packages: error.

You forgot to add your Oracle JAVA bin folder to your $PATH variable.

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin"
```

Set the above path in `/etc/environment`

Secondly,

> Could you please tell me what exactly has happened after sudo apt-autoremove. Has it messed up with any of the boot partitions or reconfigured something differently that might cause trouble?

The command

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

also detects old linux kernel versions which are no longer necessary and deletes those as well.

Currently, you have two versions of the kernel images after the command has run:

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
```

It does not look like it messed up your partition.

For more : [Is it safe to use the command apt-get autoremove in this particular scenario?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393212/is-it-safe-to-use-the-command-apt-get-autoremove-in-this-particular-scenario)