"oh no something has gone wrong. a problem has occurred and the system can't recover ubuntu" error on Ubuntu after running autoremove command
I had an error when booting up Ubuntu that read, "Oh no something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover Ubuntu". The last command I remember running before rebooting Ubuntu was sudo apt-get autoremove to remove unnecessary dependencies. I looked up several solutions until I found on the dev.to website
All I had to do was reinstall Ubuntu Desktop with the command sudo apt reinstall ubuntu-desktop. It seems some critical packages were deleted.
Originally,  I wanted to comment on this as an answer to this question but I do not have enough reputation points.
Could someone explain why the command sudo apt-get autoremove would remove critical packages (I also lost some snap packages I use such as Discord)?

That should not have happened. Autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed. Possibly there was something wrong with your dependencies. See answers at  https://askubuntu.com/questions/393212/is-it-safe-to -use-the-command-apt-get-autoremove-in-this-particular-scenario

@david, thank you for sharing the link to that discussion. The answer to the question makes sense of what just happened to me
